# How to extract LIKE in Yammer?

Tags: yammer

Currently, Admin Export function does only support post & comment thread, user, group extraction. However, I would like to get the list of who LIKE each comment? Any idea to extract such information?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this page for the API that should answer your question. 
https://developer.yammer.com/docs/usersliked_messagemessage_idjson

There isn't a way to do this in bulk but this should get you what you want.